# How to write proper java streams

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have below code snippet where I am trying to elimiate null id's from bean and sorting using comparator. I wanted to simplify the implementation using java streams can someone give a pointer how could I convert this below snippet to streams.

```
  private List<User> validateSort(List<User> users) {
    List<User> validUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : users) {
      if (user.getUserId() != null) {
        validUserList.add(user);

      }
    }
    validUserList.sort(Comparator.comparing(User::getUserId));
    return validUserList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are looking for. I am not sure how your `User` class is about, but for semplicity, I just defined with the only `userId` field.
Basically, the steps to be done are:

1. Get a stream from the list
2. Filter for all the element (User) which have non-null user ID
3. Apply the desired comparator based on `userId`
4. Collect all remaining element in a List

Here is the code you can use for test as well:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class User {
    Long userId;
    
    public User() {}
    
    public User(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "id="+userId;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> unsortedList = List.<User>of(new User((long)100), 
                                                  new User(), 
                                                  new User((long)500), 
                                                  new User((long)50), 
                                                  new User((long)33), 
                                                  new User());
        
        System.out.println("Unsorted List: " + unsortedList);
        
        List<User> validatedList = new MyClass().validateSort(unsortedList);
        
        System.out.println("Validated List: " + validatedList);
    }

    private List<User> validateSort(List<User> users) {
        return users.stream()
                    .filter(u -> u.getUserId() != null)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getUserId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
      }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Unsorted List: [id=100, id=null, id=500, id=50, id=33, id=null]
Validated List: [id=33, id=50, id=100, id=500]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to take  look at the following methods and build the `Stream` with it

- [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate))
- [`Stream#sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) that takes a `Comparator`
- [`Stream#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) if you're using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16), otherwise [`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) with [`Collectors#toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList())

Comment: That's all about Java stream. Nice one!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
users.stream().filter(user -> user.getUserId() != null).sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getUserId)).toList()
```

1. Filter the `null` user ID's.
2. Sort using non-null user ID's.
3. Return it as a list.

Comment: Nice one. Every Java develper who are used to dealing with Java streams has more or less the same idea. What a powerfull tool the Java streams is, isn't it?

Comment: They make things easy.